# SQL query to find out the last but one occurance of an element

Tags: sql, presto

For example, I have this table:

```
seenID | personID | seenTime
-------+----------+---------
   108      3         13:34
   109      2         13:56
   110      3         14:22
   111      3         14:31
   112      4         15:04
   113      2         15:52
   114      3         15:55
```

I want to get the row where the PersonID occurs for the last but one time.

So the desired output needs to be (for one of the person ID) :

```
seenID | personID | seenTime
-------+----------+---------
   111      3         14:31
```

** I am using this query to get the nth occurrence:

```
SELECT seenID,personID,seenTime FROM 
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY personID ORDER BY personID) AS row_num,* 
        FROM "YourTableName"
    )AS T
WHERE row_num = 2
```

but to get the last but one occurrence, I will not be knowing the value of n and n value will be different for different personID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track, but you want a *descending* `order by`.  That way, you always know you want the second one:

```
SELECT seenID, personID, seenTime 
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY personID
                                ORDER BY personID DESC
--------------------------------------------------^
                               ) AS row_num,
             t.* 
      FROM "YourTableName" t
     ) AS T
WHERE row_num = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `row_number()`

```
with cte as
(
select seenid,personid,seentime,
  row_number() over(partition by personid order by seentime desc) as rn
from tablename
)

select * from cte where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`min`/`max`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#max) (or `min_by`/`max_by` if needed) overload which returns an array with n largest values and combine it with `element_at` (maybe will need to wrap it in `try()`, but for Athena flavour of presto works fine as is):

```sql
WITH dataset(seenID,personID,seenTime) AS (
   VALUES 
    (108,3,'13:34'),
    (109,2,'13:56'),
    (110,3,'14:22'),
    (111,3,'14:31'),
    (112,4,'15:04'),
    (113,2,'15:52'),
    (114,3,'15:55')
 ) 
 
SELECT personID, element_at(min(seenTime, 2), 2) second_from_start, element_at(max(seenTime, 2), 2) second_from_end
FROM dataset
group by personID
```

Output:

| personID | second_from_start | second_from_end |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 14:22 | 14:31 |
| 2 | 15:52 | 13:56 |
| 4 |  |  |